# Using GeoServer WMS connected to SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, gis, vps, geoserver

I've created GeoServer WMS connected to SQL Server database.
SQL Server is on VPS, and I have to send WMS link to other organization where the GIS is.
What are the steps for that? Firewall whitelist or something else?
Thanks!

I don't know what else to do.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything if only the database is on the VPS, provided GeoServer can see it.

Comment: I don't know how to share and what to share with the other organization. Url of WMS or something else? How that data becomes visible on their GIS?

Comment: send them the WMS capabilities link from the GeoServer index page

Comment: Ok, thanks. And what are the steps on VPS, to add their IP in firewall whitelist?

Comment: the VPS is irrelevant provided they can see the GeoServer